# Prove $0\leq x\ln\left(\frac{2x}{x+y}\right)+y\ln\left(\frac{2y}{x+y}\right)$ for $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^+$

Tags: inequality

> Prove $0\leq x\ln\left(\dfrac{2x}{x+y}\right)+y\ln\left(\dfrac{2y}{x+y}\right)$ where $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^+$

Assume $x = ky$

$$0\leq ky\ln\left(\dfrac{2ky}{y(1+k)}\right)+y\ln\left(\dfrac{2y}{y(1+k)}\right)$$
$$-y\ln\left(\dfrac{2}{1+k}\right)\leq ky\ln\left(\dfrac{2k}{1+k}\right)$$
$$-\ln\left(\dfrac{2}{1+k}\right)\leq k\ln\left(\dfrac{2k}{1+k}\right)$$
$$\dfrac{2}{1+k}\leq \left(\dfrac{2k}{1+k}\right)^k$$
$$1\leq \left(\dfrac{2k}{1+k}\right)^{k-1}k^k$$

Which doesn't seem to be very helpful, but graphing the plot shows it to always being true. Is there a way to show that being the case?

Comment: I think you've lost a minus sign between first and second line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an alternative, your inequality is equivalent to:

$$x\log(2x)+y\log(2y)\geq (x+y)\log(x+y) \tag{1}$$
that is the [midpoint-convexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function) of $f(z)=z\log(z)$ over $\mathbb{R}^+$.
 Since $\frac{d^2 f}{dz^2}=\frac{1}{z}>0$, $\,f(z)$ is for sure a (midpoint-)convex function on $\mathbb{R}^+$.